# Can a cleric be non-religious?

Tags: dnd-5e

I’m planning to DM a game of DnD5e soon using the Dragon of Icespire peak and the Essentials Kit. This is for all of us as first time players.

One of the players is interested in rolling an elven Cleric, but doesn’t necessarily like the religious aspect. Is this a feasible thing for a cleric to just be interested in healing and support, rather than their gospel and the good word? Or are we better off having her choose a God/domain that simply aligns with her interests, like Nature or Life, and simply ignore or backseat the religion.

Comment: I think there's enough space between "having a god" and "being religious" for this question to be worth answering separately.

Comment: Whether or not this is a duplicate hinges on what the OP means by 'non-religious'. While we could proactively un-dupe these questions I think it might be better to wait for OP to come back and clarify whether the duped question does answer their concern - if not we can tighten up the differences between the two questions, with their guidance.

Comment: To clarify: The clarification needed is whether or not the question is if the Cleric itself needs to be "religious" in the sense of worshiping or at least believing in a particular god, or if OP means religious in the sense of whether or not cleric powers have to be provided by a god (the answer to both of these questions is no, also they're clearly different questions and we could just declare this question to be the former and remove the dupe lock).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As discussed above, could you clarify whether the linked question answers your question? Or are you actually asking about something else - if so, please clarify what you're asking so we can help provide the answer to your question. Hope you stick around! :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments everybody. I want to clarify that the duplicate does indeed answer my question. It was more along the lines of "does the cleric need a god", meaning my player is fine with the character simply choosing an "ideal" to follow.